# Web User controls

Tags: asp.net

I have created web user control in asp.net project,
I want to add Web user control dynamic in form multiple
how to dynamic web User control  in Data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LoadControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) method

**Example :**

```
Control CT = LoadControl("Control Path");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CT);
```

Comment: I want to add in html table in one column